# Replace text after importData function

Tags: google-sheets

I am using importData function in Google Spreadsheet to import an external csv file. It works, but I want to replace some text in the table.

If am not wrong for replacing text there is a function:

```
SUBSTITUTE("search for it","search for","Google")
```

The problem: when I am trying to use SUBSTITUTE I get error:

> Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A3

Is there any way to import csv and replace text in the document?

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrayformula and substitute along with importdata to replace or remove data. For example, I used this to replace '=" and double quotes with blanks:

```
=arrayformula(substitute(SUBSTITUTE( IMPORTDATA("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=downloadMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1") ,char(61) , "" ),char(34),""))
```